# Given a sorted array which is rotated 'N' times. Find the value of 'N'. The array can have duplicate elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

for example if input is (1,2,3,4,1) ans is 4 
 (1,2,3,4)->0
(5,1,2,3)->1
If array does not contain duplicate elements,it is very simple to solve (using modified binary search) but here,it contains duplicate elements ?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

I think the original O(log N) approach will no longer work in your case where the array contains duplicate elements.

Since there are duplicate elements, you cannot rule out half of the array elements when searching for the "turning point" (The point where the array element is the max element, followed by the min element)

For example: {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, a[0] = a[5] = a[(0+5)/2] = 1.
You cannot discard half of the elements as there's not enough information indicating where the turning point lies.

So, a pretty straight forward way would be the O(N) sequential search for the turning point.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_rot(a):
    m = min(a)
    x = float("-inf")
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
      if x > e:
        return i
      x = e
    return 0
```

Find the first number that is smaller than the previous one: that'll be the spot where the maximum rolls over to minimum. If there's no such spot, then the array wasn't rotated.

Comment: Yeah ,got it,its simple

Comment: Can't we do better?in terms of complexity